# jQuery validate post error message under input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello stackoverflow members . I  need to show errors messages generated by jQuery validate plugin under each input that have not pass the validation. How can i set this messages in errorPlacement function? Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    //Preiau mesajele de erroare pentru form 

    var language = $("#lang").val();
    var firstname = $("#fname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lname").val();
    var email_req = $("#em_req").val();
    var email = $("#em").val();
    var email_remote =$("#email_remote").val();
    var country = $("#cntry").val();
    var city = $("#cit").val();
    base_url=base_url+"/admin/"+language+"/adduser/";
    $("#success_message").hide();
    $("#addnewuser").validate({

            rules:{
                firstname: {
                    required:true,
                },
                lastname:{
                    required:true,
                },
                email:{
                    required:true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: base_url+"checkemail",
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype:"JSON",
                        data:{
                            email: function(){
                                return $("#email").val();   
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                country: {
                    required:true,
                },
                city:{
                    required:true,
                },
            },

            messages:{
                firstname: {
                    required:firstname,
                },
                lastname:{
                    required:lastname,
                },
                email:{
                    required:email_req,
                    email: email,
                    remote:email_remote,
                },
                country: {
                    required:country,
                },
                city:{
                    required:city,
                },
            },
            errorPlacement:function(error,element){

            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:base_url+"addUser",
                            dataType: "html",
                            data: $("#addnewuser").serialize(),
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data == true)
                                {
                                    $("#success_message").show();
                                }       
                            }
                        });
                    return false;
                }

        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this. I need to set this errorPlacement function like this.

```
errorPlacement:function(error,element){
                 error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().after());
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can do it as follows :

         $("#addnewuser").validate({
                                   invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
                                       var errors = "Errors found, Please check your information";
                                       if (errors) {

                                           $("div.error-banner").show();
                                           $("div.success-banner").hide();

                                       } else {

                                           $("div.error-banner").hide();
                                       }

                                   },
                                   success: function(label) {
                                        var lblMsg = "This field is validated"
                                        label.html(lblMsg).addClass("checked");
                                        $(".checked").prev().addClass("checked-field");
                                    },
                                    highlight: function(element) {
                                        $(element).addClass("error");
                                        $(element).removeClass("checked-field");
                                        $(element).next(".error").remove();
                                        $(element).next().removeClass("checked");


                                    },
                                   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                       error.insertAfter(element);
                                   },
                                     ignore: ".hide input"

                               });


    if($.validator){
    $.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required, requiredMessage);
    }

$.validator.addClassRules("required-field", { 
                           cRequired: true
                       });

where requiredMessage is your variable for setting the message.
```